# How to correctly deploy a Blazor Server app on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, blazor-server-side, minikube, nginx-ingress

I am trying to deploy a test Blazor server-side application in a local Kubernetes cluster. I have it configured such that I can access it via either the service or an nginx-ingress. However, both routes have their own problems that make the application not function properly once served.

When served over the service, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPBqK.png). I believe this is how it is supposed to look. However, there are a bunch of errors that make it so that I can't intereact with the page at all.
Errors:

```
blazor.server.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://172.25.217.142:30500/_blazor?id=1qrCqjxomf15Rd6QTY11rw' failed: 
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:1 [2024-01-23T20:20:31.036Z] Information: (WebSockets transport) There was an error with the transport.
blazor.server.js:1 [2024-01-23T20:20:31.036Z] Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
log @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:1 [2024-01-23T20:20:31.107Z] Warning: Failed to connect via WebSockets, using the Long Polling fallback transport. This may be due to a VPN or proxy blocking the connection. To troubleshoot this, visit https://aka.ms/blazor-server-using-fallback-long-polling.
log @ blazor.server.js:1
:30500/_blazor?id=eC3fba0OdI6vu_KNZl9_Kg:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
blazor.server.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code '404'
    at ut.send (blazor.server.js:1:39443)
    at async rt (blazor.server.js:1:36427)
    at async _t._sendLoop (blazor.server.js:1:61855)
:30500/_blazor?id=eC3fba0OdI6vu_KNZl9_Kg:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
blazor.server.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code '404'
    at ut.send (blazor.server.js:1:39443)
    at async rt (blazor.server.js:1:36427)
    at async _t._sendLoop (blazor.server.js:1:61855)
:30500/_blazor?id=eC3fba0OdI6vu_KNZl9_Kg:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
blazor.server.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code '404'
    at ut.send (blazor.server.js:1:39443)
    at async rt (blazor.server.js:1:36427)
    at async _t._sendLoop (blazor.server.js:1:61855)
:30500/_blazor?id=eC3fba0OdI6vu_KNZl9_Kg:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
blazor.server.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code '404'
    at ut.send (blazor.server.js:1:39443)
    at async rt (blazor.server.js:1:36427)
    at async _t._sendLoop (blazor.server.js:1:61855)
```

It appears that there is some problem with the WebSockets, but I don't know how to fix that.

When served over the ingress, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqwh8.png). This is obviously not correct, but I'm only getting one error:

```
blazor.server.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

I don't know what file that is because I can't open it from the DevTools Console and I am unable to locate it in the DevTools Source pane. It doesn't appear to be in the codebase for the application either.

I am running Minikube on Windows Hyper-V. The application is the default server-side Blazor application from Visual Studio 2022. I made some alterations to the default Dockerfile though:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApp.csproj", "WebApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApp/./WebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApp"
RUN dotnet build "./WebApp.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./WebApp.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

Any clues as to what could be causing these two issues?

Edit: Here are my Kubernetes .yaml files:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: blazor
  labels:
    app: blazor
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: blazor
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: blazor
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: blazor
        image: registry/...
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:  
      - name: test-webapp
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: blazor
  name: blazor
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30500
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: blazor
  type: NodePort
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: blazor-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "affinity"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "14400"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "14400"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: blazor.test
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: blazor
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: Try remove `rewrite-target` from ingress rule

Comment: The problem with the service was that I had >1 replica in the deployment, so the websocket was getting confused or something. I'm going to try to find some way to make >1 replica work.

Comment: @zori your recommendation fixed the ingress. Do you know why?

Comment: I wrote an answer with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 2 issues here

- Ingress route
- SignalR with LoadBalancer

## Ingress route

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
```

Rewrite has `$1` it means to place first `capturing group`, but what is it? Well it's something that can be used only when `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex` is added, so it just doesn't make sens, when request is send to get for file like `/styles.css` it would end up with something like `/$1styles.css` in Blazor app or anything else but not valid from your app point of view.

You can have for example

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: blazor-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "affinity"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "14400"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "14400"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: blazor.test
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: blazor
                port:
                  number: 80
```

And everything should work, but rewrite `/`(`path: /`) to `/`(`rewrite-target: /` end with what we had at beginning, so removing line with `rewrite-target` has exactly same effect.

Another example using regex

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: blazor-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "affinity"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "14400"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "14400"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: blazor.test
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: blazor
                port:
                  number: 80
```

In this case in `path` we have `/(.*)` and we have one `capturing group` what is `(.*)`(to make path `/` work correctly you must have `*` instead of `+`), then `rewrite` comes in and it says `/$1` as we have regex enabled in place of `$1` the value stored in first capturing group will be used here.

## SignalR with LoadBalancer

SignalR to establish connection with with Blazor backend needs to send 2 request

- Negotiate
- Connect

The first one will send `connectionToken` in the response then this token will be used to connect, so if you have more then one replica there is a chance(with number of replica it's growing) that those two requests will end in two different one. To resolve it [Microsoft suggest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-8.0#kubernetes) suggest using some additional annotations to force ingress(nginx) to use always the same replica based on cookie, so `Negotiate` and `Connect` will always hit the same replica and issue will not occur(also some [GitHub issue about it](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18705).

To answer the question why it doesn't work with `NodePort` as we already got it sends two request they have to hit the same replica, but service `NodePort` doesn't have feature like `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity` to force requests to the same replica all the time, and there is no solution for it expect using just one replica(or at least I don't know).